# Prestashop 1.7 - Unable to install module - Oauth required

Tags: oauth, prestashop

I am trying to install a prestashop module, but I see this error message everytime I try to download it: "In order to install this module you need to first install/enable the Oauth libraries on your Prestashop server.". It seems that it needs the oAuth library to be installed. Does any of you know how to configure it for Prestashop to recognize it?

The link to the module: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/third-party-data-integrations-crm-erp/32699-quickbooks-connector.html

I tried downloading an oauth module: https://github.com/jcarloscid/oauthsso/blob/master but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: This is a paid module, so why don't ask the developer directly which are the installation requirements ?

Comment: You say "I tried downloading an oauth module but couldn't get it to work." but don't mention what you tried. It seems your real problem is installing the OAuth module, so add some information on what the problem is when trying to install that module. Include what you've tried and any error messages.

Comment: The developer wasn't helpful, he told me to contact the system administrator.

Comment: As for the oauth module (https://github.com/jcarloscid/oauthsso), it just loads the settings indefinitely and doesn't allow me to go any further, regardless of the information I put (valid or invalid).

Answer (score 0):

Most hosting companies (thankfully) have firewall's active.
You might want to ask/check if Oauth is allowed, and ask if you van whitelist the destination's IP for your hosting package.